# How to avoid complete rollback when unique ID's also present in the transactions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Sample code : assume 3 is duplicate and 10 is the new one

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO sampletable1 VALUES (3, 'rask')
        INSERT INTO sampletable1 VALUES (10, 'SUDT')
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR
END CATCH
```

The above code, transaction is rolled back with an error.

We need to present error message for duplicate and insert for unique one without failing complete transaction.

Comment: Then you'll need to test for existing data; a transaction by definition either succeeds or fails. You should hopefully be setting xact_abort on also.

Comment: If you want `10` to still be inserted, why do you have a `ROLLBACK` in the catch for when *any* error occurs..?

Comment: @ThomA Urgh another `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()` why do people keep doing this?

Comment: I can only *assume* there's some kind of bad advice out there somewhere, @Charlieface . Probably in the same place where `NOLOCK` is labeled under "Go faster", and `ROLLBACK` in a `TRIGGER` is labeled under "contraints".

Comment: @ThomA "The docs" might be one such place to find those ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#j-use-trycatch and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-using-a-dml-after-trigger-to-enforce-a-business-rule-between-the-purchaseorderheader-and-vendor-tables

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: If you need the error(s) use batches, and have the application call for each row. If you don't need the error(s), then use an `EXISTS` to omit rows that exist.

---

Like [Stu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15332650/stu) stated, you could check for if the row already exists, and then just *not* inserting it. Something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.sampletable1 (SomeInt, SomeString)
SELECT SomeInt, SomeString
FROM (VALUES(3, 'rask'),
            (10, 'SUDT'))V(SomeInt,SomeString)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.sampletable1 st1
                  WHERE st1.SomeInt = V.SomeInt);
```

This, however, won't generate an error.

If you *must* have the error, the obvious method would be to do each `INSERT` in its own batch. Assuming this is coming from an application, then you'd need to just loop through in the application (we don't know what your application code is, so can't offer insight). In t-SQL, it would simply be:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.sampletable1 (SomeInt, SomeString) VALUES (3, 'rask');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.sampletable1 (SomeInt, SomeString) VALUES (10, 'SUDT');
```

When the first batch fails, the next batch would be started.

If you don't want to use batches an alternative and really "hacky" way to still get the error, but to continue on, would be to use deferred statements as then the errors inside still propagate to the outer scope, however, are not *aborting* errors. Assuming that you're using something like a table variable parameter to get the dataset to the SQL layer, you'd need to loop through the rows instead (yuck), but this gives you the principle:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int PRIMARY KEY,
                            SomeString varchar(4));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ID,
                           SomeString)

VALUES(3,'Pota');
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(ID,SomeString) VALUES(@ID,@SomeString);',
        @Params nvarchar(MAX) =  N'@ID int, @SomeString varchar(4)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, 3, 'rask';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, 10, 'SUDT';
GO

SELECT ID,
       SomeString
FROM dbo.SomeTable;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```